# How to support Allman Style coding in Go?

Tags: coding-style, go

In all the projects I've worked with in other languages the bracing-style of choice has been the Allman Style(aka ANSI style). The lack of a free-form bracing style(parenthesis too) is something I miss from other C-style syntax family of languages when working in Go.

Can anyone come up with a way to make the Go compiler accept the following bracing-style?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() 
{
    f()
    fmt.Println("Returned normally from f.")
}

func f() 
{
    fmt.Println("In function f.")
}
```

Note I am aware of the arguments for why Go was designed with such artificial 'limitation', but I'm not really buying into it. I'm a firm believer that the bracing-style used should really be decided by the coding-standard adopted by the people or company working on the code-base rather than being forced upon by the language itself.

As such please consider my question within the scope of 'how it can be done' rather than 'why not to do it and just adapt'.

Thanks

Comment: Golly, I didn't realise that Go enforced a braces style! This may explain its high (not) take-up rate.

Comment: Python however is pretty popular :)

Comment: @radu python isn't as big of a deal because we're indenting on code anyway -- at least if we want them readable.

Comment: Precisely. If you enforce a brace style, you can effectively get rid of the braces altogether. Not a good idea, IMHO, although I quite like python it's despite the indentation stuff, not because of it.

Comment: Is there a good reason, other than (personal) preference, to use that brace style rather than the Go one? IMO such small coding style difference are not really a problem of learning. After a day or 2 you can read and write them like any other. And personally, I like that it has been defined, so you at least have a common coding style across programs and libraries. (There may even be a good reason why they chose to enforce them, and to place them like that. Maybe the spec tells.)

Comment: The whole point of forcing a style with `gofmt` is, to have a consistent coding style. Consistent medium style is better then inconsistent superb style. And you may want to use code others has written.

Comment: In Go the bracing style is part of the language syntax. Would somebody also ask how to use {} instead of () in Scheme? In any case, one of the wonderful things about Go is that it does away with many of this pointless bikeshed discussions.

Comment: @uriel Actually it's because of Go trying to enforce this at the language level that discussions like [this](https://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/a04726569ac90e8/67040f895b68e114?q=open+brace&lnk=nl&) show up which I believe you're familiar with.

Comment: Really pointless discussions, because there is only one right way to do it in Go. And this is a good thing or *every* Go project would have to endure such a discussion when deciding what style to use.

Comment: @uriel Really pointless comment, telling people what language failings and inflexibilities they should be willing to tolerate and whether their discussion has value.

Comment: Having worked 15 years with both styles I still consider Allman far more readable than K&R – even the most exotic Horstmann style is much better in this respect. Most people I met (and discussed styles at all!) agreed on that, too. So far the argument (subjective one, sure) for wanting to have Allman style supported...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to https://gofork.org

forkgo supports allman/horstmann style:

```
package main
import
(   "fmt"
)


func main()
{   if false
    {   fmt.Println("jack")
        fmt.Println("forkgo")
    } else
    {   fmt/
           .Println("hello")
        fmt.Println("forkgo")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I double the braces up.

```go
if x < 0 {
{
    return sqrt(-x) + "i"
}}
```

It's not ideal but better than trying to scan columns 1-120 for matching braces.

Answer (score 7):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it is one possible way.

You could write a 'translator program,' essentially an incredibly simple compiler that converts from what you wrote, effectively a Go variant, to what the Go compiler itself expects.

You could do that with something along the lines of a program, even shell script, that applies the regular expression 's/(\n)$^\s*{/{\1/g' to the entire program (though it would need to look at the full string of the file and not break it up line-by-line, so you couldn't just pass that expression as an argument to sed, for example). Then write the converted file out to a temporary one, and run the Go compiler on it.

This method has the advantage of not requiring any changes to Go itself, though the disadvantage is that your files will not compile without your extra script. If you normally use a Makefile, this is probably fine, but sometimes could still be inconvenient.

Comment: You don't need to write anything. `gofmt` will do this for you.

Comment: @MrAlpha The last time I tried this this is not true. `gofmt` itself also rejects any Allman formatted source -- if `gofmt` cannot take that as input how can I use it to convert into go's style?

Answer (score 6):

Succinctly, no.  The language is (or was a year or more ago) defined with semi-colons, and the compiler inserts semi-colons implicitly at the ends of lines - unless there's a brace at the end of the line.  So, if you write a condition (which doesn't need the parentheses, please note) and do not put an open brace at the end of the line, then the Go compiler inserts one for you - leaving a null statement after the `if`, and the braces enclosing a block that is executed unconditionally.

[@epw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793540/epw) suggests a reformatter; I think that is a reasonable suggestion.  Go comes with `gofmt` to convert to the canonical Go style.  You'd have to write something to convert from canonical to Allman style, and vice versa, and ensure that you pre-compile your Go-Allman source into Go-canonical format before compiling it to object files.  On the whole, this is more traumatic than accepting that Go has its own rules which are no more eccentric than Python's rules and that it is simplest to go with the flow and accept that coding in Go involves coding in non-Allman (approximately K&R) style.  (I like and use Allman style in C; I use Go-style in Go.)